# How to read data from a string variable in sections?

Tags: java

I am creating web-app when you can create your own database usign diagram ER.
Generally after create diagram ER you can press button "generete database" and SQL code should be executed. And here is my problem...
I have that string:

```
CREATE USER "Company" IDENTIFIED BY "null"; 
CREATE TABLE Table0 (
);
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
);
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
);
```

And because "Oracle's JDBC driver may only allow one statement to be executed at a time" I need to execute this code in parts.

**Can anyone give me an example of creating a function that will write to the temporary string value everything from semicolon to semicolon?**
What i mean?

For example:

```
// first loop iteration
var tmp = ... // tmp == "CREATE USER "Company" IDENTIFIED BY "null";"

// second loop iteration
var tmp = ... // tmp == "CREATE TABLE Table0 ();"

// third loop iteration
var tmp = ... // tmp == "CREATE TABLE Table1 ();"

// fourth loop iteration
var tmp = ... // tmp == "CREATE TABLE Table2 ();"
```

I'm having trouble creating this type of loop. I don't really know how to search this string correctly.

Comment: [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String.split(), like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String statementString = new String("CREATE USER \"Company\" IDENTIFIED BY \"null\";CREATE TABLE Table0 ();CREATE TABLE Table1 ();CREATE TABLE Table2 ();");
    String[] statementArray = statementString.split(";");
    for (String statement : statementArray) {
        System.out.println(statement);
    }
}
```